# Yield all full root-leaf paths through tree structure in Python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911296/1870832) in two ways:

- I want to make the traverse function a class method, and
- I want a call to traverse to yield the list of all root-to-leaf paths (list of lists) in the tree

First change was trivial, second one I'm struggling with. Here's my class definition:

```
class createnode:
    """ thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911296/1870832"""
    def __init__(self,nodeid):
        self.nodeid=nodeid
        self.child=[]

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"{self.nodeid}")

    def traverse(self, path = []):
        path.append(self.nodeid)
        if len(self.child) == 0:
            #print(path)
            yield path
            path.pop()
        else:
            for child in self.child:
                child.traverse(path)
            path.pop()
```

I construct a tree with:

```
ROOT_NODE = 0
root = createnode(ROOT_NODE)
lvl1 = [createnode(1), createnode(2), createnode(3)]
root.child += lvl1

root.child[0].child += [createnode(4), createnode(5)]
root.child[1].child += [createnode(6), createnode(7)]
root.child[2].child += [createnode(8), createnode(9)]
```

Desired output for printing all full root-leaf paths (e.g. w/ code below)

```
paths = root.traverse()
for p in paths:
    print(p)
```

is:

```
[0, 1, 4]
[0, 1, 5]
[0, 2, 6]
[0, 2, 7]
[0, 3, 8]
[0, 3, 9]
```

Comment: I'd suggest a more stringent test case - with greater tree depth.

Comment: I get the error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'traverse'` for the line: `child.traverse(path)`

Comment: sorry quamrana I should have used `children = [createnode(32), createnode(5)]`, this `children...` statement was a more complicated list comprehension before and I accidentally over-simplified it for this question

Comment: thanks dstromberg you're right. updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into a recursive generator.

I have corrected your setup code:

```
class createnode:
    """ thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911296/1870832"""
    def __init__(self,nodeid):
        self.nodeid=nodeid
        self.child=[]

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"{self.nodeid}")

    def traverse(self, path = None):
        if path is None:
            path = []
        path.append(self.nodeid)
        if len(self.child) == 0:
            yield path
            path.pop()
        else:
            for child in self.child:
                yield from child.traverse(path)
            path.pop()

ROOT_NODE = 0
root = createnode(ROOT_NODE)
children = [createnode(32), createnode(5)]

root.child += children

paths = root.traverse()
for p in paths:
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
[0, 32]
[0, 5]
```

Comment: confirmed gives all full paths on updated larger test case. thanks again! just trying to wrap my head around `yield from` now, I hadn't even realized that exists. starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109157/1870832

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with yield yet but I'd do it like this:

```
class createnode:
    """ thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911296/1870832"""
    def __init__(self,nodeid):
        self.nodeid=nodeid
        self.child=[]

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"{self.nodeid}")

    def traverse(self, path = []):
        path.append(self.nodeid)
        if len(self.child) == 0:
            print(path)
            path.pop()
        else:
            for child in self.child:
                child.traverse(path)
            path.pop()
ROOT_NODE = 0
root = createnode(ROOT_NODE)
lvl1 = [createnode(1), createnode(2), createnode(3)]
root.child += lvl1

root.child[0].child += [createnode(4), createnode(5)]
root.child[1].child += [createnode(6), createnode(7)]
root.child[2].child += [createnode(8), createnode(9)]

root.traverse()
```

[0, 1, 4]

[0, 1, 5]

[0, 2, 6]

[0, 2, 7]

[0, 3, 8]

[0, 3, 9]

Comment: Hey I really like this solution (+1), I originally tried with `return` instead of `yield` but messed it up and came to think it required `yield.` This doesn't give my desired outcome on trees of depth 3 though. I think this is my fault for not specifying a good enough test case as @dstromberg suggested. Updating my question now...

Comment: updated question to reflect desired root-to-leaf paths only and with new better test case

Comment: your solution still works in the new case if you just call print and only call traverse once, see changes

Comment: so now you're printing each path one at a time, but not returning to a function caller a list of all full paths. I think that's what's difficult to do without yield? The question I originally mentioned that I was trying to modify already will print all the unique paths. But I'm trying to get a 2d list of list (or a generator of lists) back from a call to traverse

Comment: I see, having tried to do it without using yield, it's definitely tough. I could do with researching yield myself